# Get multiline string of textfile within block of two string using regular expression C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a text file and the following are its contents:

```
   initTest   
1234 567 8910
1234 567 8910
   endTest   

   initTest   
1234 567 8911
1234 567 8911
   endTest   

   initTest   
1234 567 8912
1234 567 8912
   endTest
```

and then I need to get the number of block within "initTest" (there are 3 white space before and after the word) and "endTest" (there are 3 white space before and after the word) and save the element of the block to array X. The result should be,
X[0] = {"1234 567 8910 \n 1234 567 8910"}
and X.length = 3.

I've tried by following code in C# using Regex but the result is none match.

```
string text = line;
string search = @"(^\s*initTest.*?^\s*endTest)";

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, search, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

Console.WriteLine("there was {0} matches for '{1}'", matches.Count, search);

Console.ReadLine();
```

I really appreciate anykind of clue and help. Thankyou very much in advance.

Comment: What is the contents of `text` before you run your Regex test against it?

Comment: @Jasen, actually the text above is not the real case one, it is a simplified case of the real one. The contents of real textfile I have  are multiline string. Inform me if the answer is not clear, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
(?<=initTest)(.|\n)*?(?=endTest)
```

where

```
initTest(.|\n)*?endTest
```

will capture required text but includes initTest and endTest. Using (?<=...) and (?=...) will help to get rid of them.

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tiXRut

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex :

```
var text = @"
   initTest   
1234 567 8910
1234 567 8910
   endTest   

   initTest   
1234 567 8911
1234 567 8911
   endTest   

   initTest   
1234 567 8912
1234 567 8912
   endTest   
";

var pattern = string.Join(@"\s+", 
    @"\s+initTest",
    @"(?<sequence1>\d{4} \d{3} \d{4})",
    @"(?<sequence2>\d{4} \d{3} \d{4})",
    @"endTest");
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline)
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => new
    {
        Content = x.Value,
        Sequence1 = x.Groups["sequence1"].Value,
        Sequence2 = x.Groups["sequence1"].Value,
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    string search = @"(?<=initTest)(.|\n)*?(?=endTest)";
    string text = GetData();

    MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text, search, RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    Console.WriteLine("there were {0} matches for '{1}'", matches.Count, search);

    for(int i=0; i < matches.Count; i++)
        Console.WriteLine(matches[i].Groups[0].ToString());

    Console.ReadLine();
}

public string GetData()
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.AppendLine("   initTest");
    sb.AppendLine("1234 567 8910");
    sb.AppendLine("1234 567 8910");
    sb.AppendLine("   endTest");

    sb.AppendLine("   initTest");
    sb.AppendLine("1234 567 8911");
    sb.AppendLine("1234 567 8911");
    sb.AppendLine("   endTest");
    sb.AppendLine(" ");
    sb.AppendLine("   initTest");
    sb.AppendLine("1234 567 8912");
    sb.AppendLine("1234 567 8912");
    sb.AppendLine("   endTest");

    return sb.ToString();   
}
```

Comment: Thanks, your  pattern is equal with pattern given by smirnov and yes,,that is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to do it without regular expression, you may try this solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string path = @"C:\Projects\StackOverRegX\StackOverRegX\input.txt";
        string[] x = new string[100];
        int index = 0;
        if (File.Exists(path))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(path))
            {
                string s = "";
                while ((s = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    if(s.Contains("initTest"))
                    {
                        x[index] = sr.ReadLine() + " \n " + sr.ReadLine();
                        index++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            if(x[i]!=null)
            Console.WriteLine(x[i]);
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```